# Template to run tensorflow light model on android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification, microsoft-custom-vision

I am creating tensorflow light model using https://www.customvision.ai/ which allows to generate image classificaiton model and export it to tensorflow lite model.

I created the model but I am not able to use it.

I tried - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-android-customvision-sample?tab=readme-ov-file
But its not running and fails at gradle. I am not Android expert so could not figure out gradle issue.

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart
This code is running on android app. But problem is I can not use my custom model in it.

I tried few more github repo which ended up either in gradle or not allowing me to use my own custom model.

I need help with

1. Template android project where can I replace tensorflow model to run my own custom model
2. Give me steps how to create my own project with custom tf lite model

Any reference article or github link is highly appreciated